# Angular 9 do synchronized call that waits before doing anything else

Tags: angular, synchronization

I have a Angular 9 application and what I want is when somebody visits my website that I do a Synchronized rest endpoint call and using the receiving data I can fill data in different components like color and currency type. Without this information the components won't produce the right formatting or colors.

Right now I have a service that gets the hostname from `window.location.hostname` and then I do a backend call. I saw online that you can do a `async` and `await` combination to make the rest call synchronized. `await` works great however the `async` part is a disaster. The reasons why I say this is that this causes the rest of the website to build including the components. This means the components are missing information that they should get from the service because they continue to load/build while the service is still doing the rest call.

I need a a way to do a synchronized call in Angular and have the entire website wait before that information is downloaded. Hoe can I do this?

Comment: Hi Martijn! Can you post some code to see what you've tried and how are your calls structured? The solution is probably simpler than you think and could be handled with ngIf and the async pipe.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this will be possible taking into consideration that the browser API handles all the ajax and asset http calls asynchronously and this cannot be changed from what I know. Also, I don't think that async / await would work because they are just a syntactic sugar for the [promise api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). Could you try maybe this approach?

- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9047#issuecomment-224075188
- https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-use-the-app-initializer-token-to-hook-into
  I suggest adding it to providers[] in app.module like in the second link:

```js
   {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: appInitializer,
      deps: [SomeService, ], // in case you need any dependencies
      multi: true,
    },
```

Comment: It does make sense to do this while the application is initializing. I'll gives it ago this weekend.